# How to define global variables in Angular 2 in a way that I can use them for property binding in templates?

Tags: data-binding, angular

In my Angular 2 (beta 14) application I need to keep track of user login status in order to hide/display certain elements.

The issue I'm getting is that property binding is not working the way I did as follows.

I created a class to store and update global variables:

**app-global.ts**

```
 import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";

 @Injectable() export class AppGlobals {
   // use this property for property binding
   public isUserLoggedIn: boolean = false;

   setLoginStatus(isLoggedIn){
       this.isUserLoggedIn = isLoggedIn;
   }

   getLoginStatus(){
       return this.isUserLoggedIn;
   } }
```

In the login component I import AppGlobals

```
export class LoginComponent {
    constructor(private _appGlobals: AppGlobals) { }
```

and set login state by

> this._appGlobals.setLoginStatus(true);

In another component I inject AppGlobals as I do in LoginComponent

I define a class (component)'s property

> isLoggedIn: boolean = this._appGlobals.isUserLoggedIn; // I also tried by using the getter instead of the public property (see above)

which I then use in the component's template to show/hide a certain element:

```
<!-- here I also tried with {{!isLoggedIn}} but results in a syntax error whereas using [(hidden)] instead of [hidden] changes nothing -->
<div id="some-element" [hidden] = "!isLoggedIn">
```

Finally, the binding works but **there is no update** (this component is part of AppComponent template and shown in every page) when another component (e.g. LoginComponent) sets the login status.

**EDIT** I tried to apply Gunter's answer but I get the following errors:

```
app/app-globals.ts(10,54): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
app/app-globals.ts(13,29): error TS2339: Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<boolean>'.
```

Error at line 10 comes from [SOLVED]

> public isUserLoggedIn:BehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject().startWith(false);

and it's apparently caused by BehaviorSubject expecting **1 parameter**

Error at line 13 comes from

> this.isUserLoggedIn.emit(isLoggedIn);

and it's apparently cause by a non-existing **emit** method.

Also, I don't understand how shall I use AppGlobals so that the property binding auto updates in another component (see last example before EDIT)

Further, in LoginComponent I replaced isLoggedIn boolean type with **BehaviorSubject** because isUserLoggedIn has type BehaviorSubject in AppGlobals

but

> this._appGlobals.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe(value => this.isLoggedIn = value);

returns a TypeError:

> Assigned expression type boolean is not assignable to type BehaviorSubject

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```ts
isLoggedIn: boolean = this._appGlobals.isUserLoggedIn;
```

is a one-time action that copies the value at the time when this line is executed. If you want subsequent changes to be propagated use observables

```ts
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable() 
export class AppGlobals {
// use this property for property binding
  public isUserLoggedIn:BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  setLoginStatus(isLoggedIn){
   this.isUserLoggedIn.next(isLoggedIn);
  }
}
```

and use it like:

```ts
export class LoginComponent {
    constructor(private _appGlobals: AppGlobals) {
  this._appGlobals.isUserLoggedIn.subscribe(value => this.isLoggedIn = value);
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35568924/217408

Comment: thanks for your answer. However something is not working correctly. Please check by updated question

Comment: Sorry, should be `next` instead of `emit`

Comment: thanks. however the error on line 10 is still there and I don't understand how to use isLoggedIn in another component so that it auto updates

Comment: Sorry again, should be `BehaviorSubject<boolean>(4);`. `startWith` is for `Subject`

Comment: The `getLoginStatus(){}` should be removed. Use `subscribe(...)` instead as shown in the constructor.

Comment: now errors are gone. However I had to use new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true) (instead of 4, since it's a boolean). 
Besides this code runs without errors but there is no update yet. Can you please provide a complete example (.ts + .html) for the other component (e.g. OtherComponent) which needs to use [hide] to hide a certain <div> when !isLoggedIn? thanks again :)

Comment: Ouch, seems not to be my best day. If you prepare an Plunker I'll have a closer look https://plnkr.co/edit/Is7SMn?p=info

Comment: never mind. I realized it was my mistake. In the Observable init I put true instead of false. now it's working

Comment: missing `import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";`

Comment: can't have a global variable without subscribe ?

Comment: Sure, but usually an Observable is the better option, because it notifies about value changes. This is usually much more efficient that checking repeatedly.

Comment: it is speeling mistake, isUserLoggedIn not isuserLoggedIn. so this._appGlobals.isUserLoggedIn .subscribe(value => this.isLoggedIn = value); is correct

Comment: Very clever. I would make the subject private and add a getter to return that as an `Observable` so people are forced to use `set` methods to send notifications instead of using the subject directly.

Answer (score 1):

had a similar need, ended up implementing this via  simple getter - and it binds the property in the template (--> changes propagate). less code.

you can set the global var either directly or implement setters/getters in the Globals class.

**globals.ts**

```
export class Globals{
    public static server_call_in_progress:boolean = true;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Globals} from "./shared/globals";    
export class AppComponent{  
    constructor(){}
    ngOnInit(){}

    get server_call_in_progress(){
        return Globals.server_call_in_progress;
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="server_call_in_progress">
    <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```