# Subscriber doesn't receive value from .next()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create a shared service to communicate between components using an Observable, using: http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/ as a guide:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Injectable()
export class ModalService {

  private _isOpen: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  public isOpen: Observable<boolean> = this._isOpen.asObservable();


  openModal() {
    this._isOpen.next(true);
  }

  closeModal() {
    this._isOpen.next(false);
  }

}
```

in my component(s), I subscribe to `isOpen`, which receives a value when subscribing:

```
. . .

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.modalService.isOpen.subscribe(state => {
      console.log('`isOpen` in subscription', state);
    });
  }
```

However, when I trigger `.openModal()` on the shared service instance, the subscriber never receives the new value. What am I doing wrong?

My logic was that by using a Behavior Subject, the subscriber would receive an initial value of `false`, then I could change the value on click from other components that have an instance of the shared service.

Comment: next was deprecated, try with this._isOpen.emit(true)

Comment: TypeScript is telling me: `Property 'emit' does not exist on type BehaviorSubject`

Comment: My bad, next it's fine there, it was deprecated on EventEmitter. It seems to be a DI issue, you added the modalService on your main ngModule as a provider right?

Comment: I don't get it. My use case is identical to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715918/how-to-define-global-variables-in-angular-2-in-a-way-that-i-can-use-them-for-pro and it seems to be working for that user.

Comment: If I call: `this.modalService.openModal();` in the component where I subscribe to `isOpen`, it works. If I call the same method from another component with the `modalService` injected into it, and call `.openModal()` it doesn't work.

Comment: That's good, you have multiple instances of modalService, you must have only one, check that you only have one provider for modalService, try to provide it only from your app.module.ts

Comment: I had registered the ModalService as a Provider in a shared module. I moved it to the App module and it works as expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My application has several sub-modules, and a shared module to register common components, and modules between them. I had registered the `ModalService` in the shared component.

I moved the ModalService to the Providers of the uppermost (app.module.ts) providers array, and it works as expected.

Thanks to @camaron for the tip. Note to self: never, ever register a provider in a shared module :)

Comment: @olsn I will. You have to wait a couple of days before you can accept your own answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry 'bout that :)

Comment: I spent alot of time in investigating this issue and I wonder why it only works in app.module.ts