# Behavior subject not updating subscriber on .next(value)

Tags: typescript, ionic4, subscribe, behaviorsubject, auth-guard

I am having an issue with getting a Behavior Subject to update a subscriber on the .next(value) call.

I am new to typescript but i think i must just be missing something small. it seems correct from what i have seen.

There were quite a few issues like this on the site but none of them fixed my issue. This is an example. [Subscriber doesn't receive value from .next()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865348/subscriber-doesnt-receive-value-from-next)

RestService is only put in the app.module.ts providers array.

Auth Guard File (services/auth-guard.service.ts)

```
authenticated = false;

...

    ngOnInit(){
        this.restService.isLoggedIn().subscribe({
            next: result => {
                this.authenticated = result;
            }
        });
    }

...

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean{

        console.log(this.authenticated);

        if(!this.authenticated){
            this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
        return this.authenticated;
    }
}
```

Parts of rest service file (services/rest.service.ts)

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from  '@ionic/storage';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from  'rxjs';
import { User } from  'src/app/Interfaces/user';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

authSubject  =  new  BehaviorSubject(false);

...

public _setAuthSubject(value){
    this.authSubject.next(value);
 }

public isLoggedIn() {
    return this.authSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

In canActivate I have a console log that shows that this.authenticated is always false, but if I put another subscriber call and print the other variable under this, I can see that it is actually true now  and it was properly updated. Am I missing something here that causes authenticated to not be updated?

Some additional information. Here is my app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuardService,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    SQLite,
    SQLitePorter,
    RestService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

And also the routing that calls the auth guard service (app-routing.module.ts)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule', canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Lastly here is the function that is called that actually set the auth subject to true (login/login.page.ts)

```
constructor(
    public menu: MenuController,
    private restService: RestService,
    private router: Router,
    private storage: Storage
  ) { }


  async login(form){

    this.restService.login(form.value).subscribe({
      next: response => {
        console.log(response)
        if(response.access_token){
          this.storage.set("ACCESS_TOKEN", response.access_token);
          this.restService._setToken(response.access_token);
          this.restService._setAuthSubject(true);
        }
        this.router.navigateByUrl('');
      },
      error: err => {
        console.log('ERROR!: ', err)
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: In your service you are updating authSubject  and in your component you are subscribing to isLoggedIn(). what does isLoggedIn() do ? how does it relate to authSubject  ? May be you can explain or add some code to your post

Comment: @lchraf Oh man im sorry, that would obviously help. I added that in. IsLoggedIn returns authsubject as an observable.

Comment: I looks ok for me. I don't think the problem is the behaviour subject. It migth be your DI setup. You can check if your rest service is not being re-instatiated making your guard always have the same initial value (false).

Comment: I was curious about this as well. so underneath my console.log(this.authenticated);line i added another subscribe (which would subscribe every time this function gets called), the value shows true.Or do you mean auth gaurd service (the first code snippet).

Comment: @ingkevin I am also not sure what you mean by DI setup.

Comment: By DI I ment Dependency Injection but know that you added your module definition it also seems ok.

You can try returning the `restService.isLoggedIn()` observable in your guard. By definition you can return ` Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree`.

Comment: If i understand correctly, you are saying that instead of doing the subscribe, just return the observable?

Comment: HOOZAH I FIGURED IT OUT. its because ngOnInit does not work with services.. if i stil it in the constructor it works. I know you are supposed to keep logic out of the constructer but services I guess makes it okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modified AuthGuard with the below code. Services cant have code in ngOnInit, i had no idea! Nooby mistake... thank you for all the help @ingkevin and @lchraf.

```
    init(){
        this.restService.isLoggedIn().subscribe({
            next: result => {
                this.authenticated = result;
            }
        });
    }

    constructor(private router: Router, 
                public restService: RestService) {
                    this.init()
                }
```

ngOnInit was removed.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a demo on BehaviourSubject please have a look might be helpful to solve your issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/behavioursubject-angular-demo